# How to loop in Golang without using the iterator?

Tags: go

I know this works.

```
for i :=range []int{1, 2, 3....} {
    fmt.Println(i)
}
```

But If I want to do something like:

```
for i :=range []int{1, 2, 3....} {
    code = GenNewCode()
    Insert(code)
}
```

I get an error that `i` was not used.
Is there a way I can do it without getting the above error?
(Pardon me if this is a silly question, I am just learning Golang a bit.)

Comment: No, that's valid: https://play.golang.org/p/WFHSrsjISC Please show an example with the error your'e seeing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore such things by using the [blank identifier](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#blank): `_`

```
for _ := range []int{1, 2, 3} {
    code = GenNewCode()
    Insert(code)
}
```

Or one can use (via JimB's comment)

```
for range []int{1, 2, 3}{
code = GenNewCode()
    Insert(code)
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `_`, just use `for range []int{1, 2, 3}`

Comment: Awesome! Learnt one more thing. Thanks!